# export 'default' not found when importing package with vuejs and laravel inertia

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I've installed a new laravel 8 jetstream with inertia and trying to use tiptap for wysiwy but webpack is giving the error below:

**WARNING in ./node_modules/tiptap/dist/tiptap.esm.js 111:4-21
export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'**

```
<template>
  <app-layout>
    <editor-content :editor="editor" />
  </app-layout>
</template>

<script>
import AppLayout from "@/Layouts/AppLayout";
import { Editor, EditorContent } from 'tiptap'

export default {
    components: {
        AppLayout,
        EditorContent
    },
    data() {
        return {
          editor: null,
        };
    },
    mounted() {
      this.editor = new Editor({
        content: '<p>This is just a boring paragraph</p>',
      })
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Mixing of Vue 2 and Vue 3 libraries/compilers will cause this.

Comment: I installed a fresh laravel 8 with jetstream inertia and didnt touch any compilers. @Ohgodwhy

Comment: Tiptap does not come with Inertia or Jetstream.